# API response data is not visible

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-state

I am pulling some data from Facebook API,

```
const response = await axios.get('API ENDPOINT')
     setData(response.data); // Assuming the data is in the response.data
     console.log(response.data) //printing values
     console.log('Data copied to state:', data); // Log the state after update
```

`console.log(response.data)` This one logs data correctly as JSON object in console
`console.log('Data copied to state:', data)` gives an empty array.

Accessed from HTML Element

```
{data?.length > 0 && (
      <ul>
        {data.map((item, index) => (
          <li key={index}>
            {/* Access item properties here */}
            {item.email} - {item.last_name}
          </li>
  ))}
```

How to get data populated to data object to print in HTML Element

Comment: I do something very, very similar. I've declared where to store the data `const [data, setData] = useState([]);` then I populate it and store it `setData(` and then in the return part I do this: `{data ? ( <> {data.map((e, index) => (` - the main difference I see is when I  setData I do that in a useEffect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Answer (score 0):

Setting state in React is asynchronous. This means the `setData` function doesn't immediately mutate the provided state but creates a pending state transition. This is the reason why you're seeing an empty array when you `console log` data immediately after setting it.

You may want to actually check the data in your render function or just after your `useEffect` hook if you have one.

Example:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get('API ENDPOINT')
        setData(response.data);
    }
    fetchData();
}, []);
```

You're going to show the `data` on the component, so you can't use `useRef`, so using `useEffect` is the best way I can see.

check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=42BkpGe8oxg&t=663s)

Answer (score 0):

@Kobra's answer answers the question - `setState` is asynchronous and might not reflect immediate changes of the `state`. And `useEffect` is a great tool to [synchronous components (including `state`) with an external system](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect).

As it is unclear how you use your function with the `fetch()` method; a way to check the changed value of a `state` is to put it in a `useEffect`, with `dependencies` specified. For example,

```js
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(data);
}, [data])

// The result should be something like this with `dev` mode, if set correctly:
// <initial_value>
// <initial_value>
// <updated_value>
```

And the data should populate the HTML once the state is updated - React would re-render the component when state changes (according to React's [documentation](https://react.dev/learn/state-a-components-memory)).

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing might be due to the asynchronous nature of the `setData` function call. When you log data immediately after calling `setData`, it may not have been updated yet.

Here's how you can adjust your code to ensure that data is populated correctly:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function YourComponent() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('API ENDPOINT');
        setData(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []); // Empty dependency array to ensure useEffect runs only once

  return (
    <div>
      {data.length > 0 ? (
        <ul>
          {data.map((item, index) => (
            <li key={index}>
              {/* Access item properties here */}
              {item.email} - {item.last_name}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      ) : (
        <p>No data available</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default YourComponent;
```

Comment: Did you create this answer with [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1)?

Answer (score 0):

@Kobra and @hokwanhung answered the question. I want to segregate both of the things.

```
const fetchData = async () => {
   const response = await axios.get('API ENDPOINT')
   setData(response.data);
}


useEffect(() => {
   fetchData()
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
   console.log(data)
}, [data])
```

This is how you will get the data in the console.log(). Because setData() doesn't immediately populate the response.

Then you can use that value in data to render the HTML

```
{data?.map((item) => {
   {/* JSX */}
})}
```

I hope, putting it all together makes sense for you.